# Unable to make Navigation Bar totally transparent in iOS6

Tags: ios, uikit, ios6, uinavigationbar

I was using the following code to make my Navigation Bar transparent in iOS5:

```
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Upgraded to iOS6 and the Navigation Bar is still transparent but now has a thin black line underneath it.  How can I make the Navigation Bar totally transparent?

I have also tried all of the following:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.opaque = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that your image mask isn't completely taking up the height of the bar, this leaving a black "space" where your UINavigationBar doesn't quite come flush with the view?

Comment: Solved. iOS6 has added a drop shadow to the Navigation Bar. So the masking code that I was using with iOS5 still works fine - I just need to add if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
} to get rid of the drop shadow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. iOS6 has added a drop shadow to the Navigation Bar. So the masking code that I was using with iOS5 still works fine - I just need to add

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)]) 
{ 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]]; 
}
```

to get rid of the drop shadow.

Answer (score 2):

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; // Setting this slides the view up, underneath the nav bar (otherwise it'll appear black)
    const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
//remove shadow
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(shadowImage)])           
 { 
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setShadowImage:[[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease]]; 
    // autorelease is necessary, or else [[UIImage alloc] init]'s retainCount is 2.
 }
```